# Cannot initiate jupyter notebook via clicking the shortcut

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook

I cannot initiate Jupyter Notebook by clicking its shortcuts. Whenever I click on the shortcut, the window for cmd shows up for a moment and is then closed immediately. The browser will not be opened.

**Shortcut icon for jupyter notebook:**

[image]

However, I can initiate it via the command line.  Does anyone know why this is and how I can fix this?

Comment: You must specify the os its version typing a new post.

Comment: The shortcut can be the issue. Try to
manually change the "Shortcut target"  to the following:
C:\Users\'yourusername'\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda3\Scripts\jupyter-notebook.exe